# Xcode 6 Cannot Find .pch File, Although it Exists

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting the error `clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/to/my/project/MyProject/Supporting\ Files/MyProject-Prefix.pch'` from Xcode 6.3.1 when I try to build my application.

However, this file clearly exists, since when I type (or even copy & paste the path from the error message) `$ cat /path/to/my/project/MyProject/Supporting\ Files/MyProject-Prefix.pch` into the terminal the contents of the file are printed to Stdout. The file is also linked to my Xcode, and is visible in the document outline.

Does anyone know why Xcode is not finding this file that obviously exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be in the project build settings you have "Supporting\ Files" with the backslash escaping the space in the value for "Prefix Header". The backslash should be removed.

I tried this on a test project both with and without the backslash and when editing the filename in Xcode UI the compile only worked without the backslash.
When the compile worked the pbxproj file had this value:

GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "foobar/Supporting Files/test.pch";

and the "Prefix Header" on the Xcode Build Settings showed:

foobar/Supporting Files/test.pch

The backslash is needed when typing the path in terminal to escape the space.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the short path for Prefix Header in the project settings like the following:

```
"MyProject/Supporting Files/MyProject-Prefix.pch"
```

Also it is uncommon to have folder named `Supporting Files` in your project folder and that file supposed to be right under the root

Comment: I used synx (https://github.com/venmo/synx) to consolidate and organize the files in my project, and it put my .pch file in a Supporting Files directory, since by default it was in Supporting Files group

Comment: So your problem was the backslash?

Comment: @NebulaFox even in case when path contains spaces?

Comment: @Azat even if it include spaces. The error from the compiler shows the project dir and the additional path already wrapped in quotes. (Xcode 6.3.2)